# extended initializer lists being seen as functions

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I'm trying to compile an opensource project but I'm getting this problem from g++

`error: function definition does not declare parameters`

the code is something like this

```
#include <iostream>

namespace hi {

  class hello {
 public:
    bool first { true };
  };

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  hi::hello h

  std::cout << "output: " << h.first << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which produces the same compilation problem as the code of the opensource project when compiled with

```
g++ -O2 bools.cpp -o bools -std=c++0x
```

however if I try to compile this code with the same options it compiles and runs as it should

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  bool value { true };

  std::cout << "output: " << value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 64bit.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for [non-static data member initializers](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm) was added in `gcc 4.7`. You can see the list of what *C++0x/C++11* features `gcc` supports with what versions [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). The line for this feature says:

```
Non-static data member initializers   |  N2756 |    GCC 4.7
```

This works perfectly fine in `gcc 4.7` and greater, see it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bc5b4bcc6aaee8c).